# Full humanized durations in moment.js

Tags: momentjs

I tried this in moment.js

```
moment.duration(375,'days').humanize()
```

and get **"a year"** as answer, but I would expect "a year and 10 days". Is there a way in moment.js to get the full humanized value?

Answer (score 50):

Moment.js is providing the `fromNow` function to get time durations in human readable fromat, see http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/

Example:

```
moment([2007, 0, 29]).fromNow(); // 4 years ago
moment().subtract(375, 'days').fromNow(); // a year ago
```

You need to use third party lib as suggested by @Fluffy

Comment: No need for 3rd party. You can use [`moment.relativeTimeThreshold('y', 365)`](https://github.com/moment/momentjs.com/blob/master/docs/moment/07-customization/13-relative-time-threshold.md) to set the rounding.

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Comment: Some out of subject posts are getting downvoted and not yours, I don't get it ahah. The OP originally wanted to know how to be more accurate than the default human format. His example is quite clear, 375 days turning in "1 year" is sometimes no accurate enough, and you want to display "1 year, 10 days". And take care of internationalization too.

Answer (score 28):

I found this small lib, that only display duration (if you don't really need all the features of moment.js)

https://github.com/EvanHahn/HumanizeDuration.js

Comment: example usage to show "21 minutes ago": `{humanizeDuration(moment(someDateGoesHere) - moment(), { largest: 1 })} ago`

Answer (score 15):

Try this plugin:

https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format

```
moment.duration(123, "minutes").format("h [hrs], m [min]");
// "2 hrs, 3 min"
```

Comment: It seems this plugin is not loading moment's locale properly, and will not format non-English names right. Issue: [#129](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format/issues/129)

Comment: This plugin is no more supported, last update was 3 years ago

Answer (score 11):

I was looking at the same issue and seems like there is no plan on supporting this in the future...

Although one workaround proposed is to make an language definition that *overrides* default implementation of humanized messages:

https://github.com/timrwood/moment/issues/348

Kind of an overkill if you ask me...

Answer (score 7):

Use [`moment.relativeTimeThreshold('y', 365)`](https://github.com/moment/momentjs.com/blob/master/docs/moment/07-customization/13-relative-time-threshold.md) to set the rounding.

```
moment.relativeTimeThreshold('s', 60);
moment.relativeTimeThreshold('m', 60);
moment.relativeTimeThreshold('h', 24);
moment.relativeTimeThreshold('d', 31);
moment.relativeTimeThreshold('M', 12);
moment.relativeTimeThreshold('y', 365);
```

Answer (score 5):

I made a function to solve this exact problem.

```
function formatDuration(period) {
    let parts = [];
    const duration = moment.duration(period);

    // return nothing when the duration is falsy or not correctly parsed (P0D)
    if(!duration || duration.toISOString() === "P0D") return;

    if(duration.years() >= 1) {
        const years = Math.floor(duration.years());
        parts.push(years+" "+(years > 1 ? "years" : "year"));
    }

    if(duration.months() >= 1) {
        const months = Math.floor(duration.months());
        parts.push(months+" "+(months > 1 ? "months" : "month"));
    }

    if(duration.days() >= 1) {
        const days = Math.floor(duration.days());
        parts.push(days+" "+(days > 1 ? "days" : "day"));
    }

    if(duration.hours() >= 1) {
        const hours = Math.floor(duration.hours());
        parts.push(hours+" "+(hours > 1 ? "hours" : "hour"));
    }

    if(duration.minutes() >= 1) {
        const minutes = Math.floor(duration.minutes());
        parts.push(minutes+" "+(minutes > 1 ? "minutes" : "minute"));
    }

    if(duration.seconds() >= 1) {
        const seconds = Math.floor(duration.seconds());
        parts.push(seconds+" "+(seconds > 1 ? "seconds" : "second"));
    }

    return "in "+parts.join(", ");
}
```

This function takes a period string (ISO 8601), parses it with Moment (>2.3.0) and then, for every unit of time, pushes a string in the `parts` array. Then everything inside the `parts` array gets joined together with `", "` as separation string.

You can test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/mvcha2xp/6/

I'm using it as a Vue filter to humanize durations correctly.

Comment: great to share your workaround mate, but it's too bad for internationalization, because in some languages, dispay order may change ... better than nothing yes, but I can't use it as is; I will try to see if it's easy to internationalize it with moment methods.

Comment: @Alex I don't think display order may change in other languages. I think all languages refer to a period starting by the largest unit going to the smallest one. I don't think there's a language out there in which they say "We're going to have maintenance in 15 seconds, 2 minutes, 3 hours, 5 days".

Comment: what if you wanna support i18n for units. like 18秒 in Japanese instead of 18seconds?

Comment: @OtaniShuzo Just replace "seconds" with "秒" (?)

Comment: @SyncroIT Right! but what I wanted to do is support multiple locales dynamically, so I just ended up writing locale-unit mapping code to display units in different language depending on the locale. 
I was just wondering there is some more elegant way tho.

Answer (score 3):

[This issue](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/348) on Github contains a lot of discussion about exactly that. Many are asking for a more precise humanized option.

Chime in with why you need it, use cases, etc.

https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/348

Answer (score 1):

i have written this javascript code to humanize the duration,

```
function humanizeDuration(timeInMillisecond) {
    var result = "";
    if (timeInMillisecond) {
        if ((result = Math.round(timeInMillisecond / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 * 12))) > 0) {//year
            result = result === 1 ? result + " Year" : result + " Years";
        } else if ((result = Math.round(timeInMillisecond / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 30))) > 0) {//months
            result = result === 1 ? result + " Month" : result + " Months";
        } else if ((result = Math.round(timeInMillisecond / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))) > 0) {//days
            result = result === 1 ? result + " Day" : result + " Days";
        } else if ((result = Math.round(timeInMillisecond / (1000 * 60 * 60))) > 0) {//Hours
            result = result === 1 ? result + " Hours" : result + " Hours";
        } else if ((result = Math.round(timeInMillisecond / (1000 * 60))) > 0) {//minute
            result = result === 1 ? result + " Minute" : result + " Minutes";
        } else if ((result = Math.round(timeInMillisecond / 1000)) > 0) {//second
            result = result === 1 ? result + " Second" : result + " Seconds";
        } else {
            result = timeInMillisecond + " Millisec";
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions:

```
function getCountdown() {
  // diff in seconds, comes through function's params
  const diff = 60*60*24*4 + 60*60*22 + 60*35 + 5;
  const MINUTE = 60;
  const HOUR = MINUTE * 60;
  const DAY = HOUR * 24;

  const days = Math.floor(diff / DAY);
  const hDiff = diff % DAY;
  const hours = Math.floor(hDiff / HOUR);
  const mDiff = hDiff % HOUR;
  const minutes = Math.floor(mDiff / MINUTE);
  const seconds = mDiff % MINUTE;

  return [days, hours, minutes, seconds]
    .map(v => (''+v)[1] ? ''+v : '0'+v)
}


output: ["04", "22", "35", "05"]
```

I needed it up to days only, but can be easily extended to weeks.
Doesn't make sense with months since diff says nothing about start date. 
Having a period split to parts, adding "days"/"hours"/... is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

Moment.js provides:

```
var y = moment.duration(375,'days').years(); // returns 1
var d = moment.duration(375,'days').days(); // returns 9

var data = y + 'y ' + d + 'd';

console.log(data);
```

This could be used with a bit of extra logic

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution on CoffeeScript:

```
humanizeDuration = (eventDuration)->
    eventMDuration = Moment.duration(eventDuration, 'seconds');
    eventDurationString = ""
    if (eventMDuration.days() > 0)
        eventDurationString += " " + Moment.duration(eventMDuration.days(), 'days').humanize()
    if (eventMDuration.hours() > 0)
        eventDurationString += " " + Moment.duration(eventMDuration.hours(), 'hours').humanize()
    if (eventMDuration.minutes() > 0)
        eventDurationString += " " + Moment.duration(eventMDuration.minutes(), 'minutes').humanize()

    eventDurationString.trim()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, I like it better than the others here:

```
val moment1 = moment();
val moment2 = mement();
console.log(moment.duration(moment1.diff(moment2)).humanize());
```

Comment: How does this solve the issue of the OP? This will still have the inaccurate duration.

Answer (score -1):

Based on Ihor Kaslashnikov's solution, I modified the function to be even more accurate using vanilla Javascript.

```
function momentHumanize(eventDuration, unit) {
    var eventMDuration = moment.duration(eventDuration, unit);
    var eventDurationArray = [];
    if (eventMDuration.years() > 0) {
        eventDurationArray.push(eventMDuration.years() + ' years');
        eventMDuration.subtract(eventMDuration.years(), 'years')
    }
    if (eventMDuration.months() > 0) {
        eventDurationArray.push(eventMDuration.months() + ' months');
        eventMDuration.subtract(eventMDuration.months(), 'months')
    }
    if (eventMDuration.weeks() > 0) {
        eventDurationArray.push(eventMDuration.weeks() + ' weeks');
        eventMDuration.subtract(eventMDuration.weeks(), 'weeks')
    }
    if (eventMDuration.days() > 0) {
        eventDurationArray.push(eventMDuration.days() + ' days');
        eventMDuration.subtract(eventMDuration.days(), 'days')
    }
    if (eventMDuration.hours() > 0) {
        eventDurationArray.push(eventMDuration.hours() + ' hours');
        eventMDuration.subtract(eventMDuration.hours(), 'hours')
    }
    if (eventMDuration.minutes() > 0) {
        eventDurationArray.push(eventMDuration.minutes() + ' minutes');
    }
    return eventDurationArray.length === 1 ? eventDurationArray[0] : 
    eventDurationArray.join(' and ')
}
```

This will remove any amount from the moment instance once it humanizes it. 
I did this because Ihor's solution was inaccurate, given that moment's humanize function rounds the value. For example, if I had 2.8 hours, it should've been `2 hours and an hour`. 
My solution removes the 2 hours, from the instance, leaving only 0.8 hours, and doesn't use moment's humanize function to avoid rounding.

Examples:

```
momentHumanize(45, 'minutes') // 45 minutes

momentHumanize(4514, 'minutes') // 3 days and 3 hours and 14 minutes

momentHumanize(45145587, 'minutes') // 85 years and 10 months and 1 days and 2 hours and 27 minutes
```

Comment: what about localization ?

Answer (score -3):

```js
var s=moment([2020, 03, 29]).subtract(3, 'days').fromNow(); 

document.write(s)
```

[enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/srinishith/xj95ygku/29/)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.