# How do i display time range in X days Y hours using angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to display time such that depending on the value(value will alwasy be in minutes) I add months/weeks/days/hours/minutes. For which I have come up with this function:

```
function displayTimeRange (timeValue) {
            var message;
            var dateValue = Math.floor((timeValue / 60) / 24);
            var hourValue = Math.floor(timeValue / 60);
            if (dateValue > 1) {
                message = gettextCatalog.getString("{{time}} days", {time: dateValue}, null);
            } else if (hourValue > 1) {
                message = gettextCatalog.getString("in the last {{time}} hours", {time: hourValue}, null);
            } else if (hourValue === 1) {
                message = gettextCatalog.getString("in the last {{time}} hour", {time: hourValue}, null);
            } else {
                message = gettextCatalog.getString("in the last {{time}} minutes", {time: timeValue}, null);
            }
            return message;
        }
```

In addition to that, if it is 25 hours I want it to display "1 day 1 hour" instead of rounding it up or down. I want it to be more precise like "3 hours 4minutes" or "4 days 10hours" etc.
Something like how Stackoverflow also display time:

[image]

Does angular js have any filter for that ? Can anyone please recommend some ways to do that?

Comment: What does timeValue look like? Is it a date?

Comment: timeValue will always be in minutes. so the data returned for 24hours will be 1440. After applying the function above we convert it into hours/days/weeks/months

Comment: You might look into momentJS. But usually times are dealt with via dates. Angular has a date filter, but nothing like what you're looking for

Comment: MomentJs has functions to handle durations as you say. Easiest and cleanest way

Comment: Ok thanks! will try using momentJS

Comment: @yBrodsky i used moment.duration(timeValue).humanize(); But it is not giving right result. Am i using wrong function of momentJS ?

Comment: the duration function takes a second param which is the unit of time, 'minutes' in your case. However I am testing and I see that this doesn't produce the desired result when you pass for example 61 minutes. It shows only 1 hour, missing the "and 1 minute"

Comment: As for my previous comment, check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300278/full-humanized-durations-in-moment-js

Comment: Otherwise you will have to do it by hand

Comment: Thanks for the link! I will give it a shot