# How to find the time spend between two timestamps in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have an application where the user can post something and all other users can view that post. So I want to view in that post that **how much time ago** the current post was posted, like "5 mins ago" or "2 days ago" or "Just Now", etc.

I have the server timestamp (Firebase) of the post. Let's call this variable as `timestamp`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300278/full-humanized-durations-in-moment-js

Comment: Does the answer below help you? If so, please [accept or vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a utility function using momentjs's [fromNow](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/):

```
import moment from 'moment'

export function getFromNow(
  date: moment.Moment | Date,
  suffix = 'ago'
) {
  let momentDate: moment.Moment
  if (moment.isMoment(date)) {
    momentDate = date
  } else {
    momentDate = moment(date)
  }
  return `${momentDate.fromNow(true)} ${suffix}`
}
```

Comment: You can remove the typings if you aren't using TypeScript.