# how to get a duration in human format (1 hours, 4 minutes)

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using 'moment' library. I have a duration in minutes, and I want it to be humanized.

For example:

```
const totalMinutes = 124;
console.log(moment.duration(totalMinutes, 'minutes').humanize()); // prints 2 hours
```

but that's not what I want, I want it to be:

124 => `2 hours, 4 minutes`

34 => `34 minutes // no hours`

725 => `12 hours, 5 minutes`

I don't care about days or seconds.

I know that I can somehow extract the hours and minutes and join them to make the final string, but I feel there is a shorter way at least using the library itself.
Not to mention that I want the text to be localized in other languages, which moment library itself support.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300278/full-humanized-durations-in-moment-js

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Full humanized durations in moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300278/full-humanized-durations-in-moment-js)

Comment: @RobinWebb  Thank you, unfortunately, they both don't answer my question.

I posted the answer if you are interested.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Same comment as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that Moment JS library doesn't have this out of the box, and I had to use another [library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/humanize-duration).

Here is the solution:

```
import humanizeDuration from "humanize-duration";

console.log(humanizeDuration(658 * 60 * 1000, { language: 'en'})); 
// prints 10 hours, 58 minutes
console.log(humanizeDuration(55 * 60 * 1000, { language: 'en'})); 
// prints 55 minutes
```

which is exactly what I want.